# cURL PHP login url post 302

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou com problema a fazer autenticação em um sistema e usando o componente

> live http header no mozilla

eu consigo pega sabe a url do post e com curl pode automatizar 
veja a imagem do retorno do live http
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e o meu code eu fiz assim

```
    $ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlPost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded')); #Json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, ''); #Json
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

mais a url do post que tive que tampa está dando location e no curl não consegue completa o post , alguém consegue me ajuda e orienta como devo fazer para que funciona ?

Comment: Boa noite, gostaria de saber se a resposta lhe ajudou, se não por favor comente o que acha que falta.

Answer (score 2):

Na verdade está indo "perfeito", o problema é que você não habilitou o redirecionamento, para isto use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Use desta maneira:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlPost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded')); #Json
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, ''); #Json
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```