# Banco do Brasil, segunda viua de boleto: não consiga enviar POST para https://www63.bb.com.br/portalbb/boleto/boletos/hc21e,802,3322,10343.bbx

Tags: php

Preciso implementar consulta web à segunda via de boletos do BB, a partir da página https://www63.bb.com.br/portalbb/boleto/boletos/hc21e,802,3322,10343.bbx.

Devo enviar o CNPJ e o número do documento, ele retorna o captcha, que o usuário precisa digitar, então envio todos os dados pelo formulário.

Mas não consigo nem ler a página https://www63.bb.com.br/portalbb/boleto/boletos/hc21e,802,3322,10343.bbx, a resposta que tenho é:

> This document you requested has moved temporarily.
>
> It's now at
>   https://www63.bb.com.br/portalbb/boleto/error.bbx;jsessionid=HW8iAwOjliGFNl1-_5UHxnF3Ompa5vosJ0VvswNxLfjP4GK2ySuN!-536097846?cid=580485

E a cada acesso, ele gera um ID de sessão e um código diferente. Quando tento acessar essa página, dá o mesmo erro.

Estou acessando com cURL, alguém  tem alguma luz?

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente isto indica que houve um redirecionamento HTTP de código 302:

> This document you requested has moved temporarily.

Como eu respondi em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/71283/3635

Deve usar o `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, exemplo:

```
$urlPost = '<site>';
$post_fields = array(
  .... //items do formulário
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlPost);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); //passa o user-agent atual para o curl

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Claro que isto não resolverá todos os problema, ainda mais que eles usarem um anti-bot, ou um anti-CSRF, o que não existe solução pratica para burlar.

Comment: Guilherme, exatamente isso !!!!Funcionou perfeitamente e resolveu o meu problema !!! :-)

Comment: @LucianaCorreia otimo, por favor aproveita e marque a resposta como correta, se não souber como fazer leia isto: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3635 - fico agradecido!